# Logstash Configuration Issue - JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am getting below error:

> LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unexpected character ('.' (code 46)): Expected space separating root-level values

Below is my logstash.conf

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
type => beats
codec => json_lines
}
gelf {
port =>5043
type => xxx
}
tcp {
port => 5045
codec => json_lines
type => xxx
}
}
filter {
if [type] == "beats" {
json {
source => "message"
}}

if [type] == "beats" {
geoip {
source => "remote_ip"
target => "geoip"
database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
}
mutate {
convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
}}
}
output {
if [type] == "beats" {
amazon_es {
hosts => [“xxx”]
region => “xx”
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
codec => "json"
}
}
if [type] == "ecs" {
amazon_es {
hosts => [“xx”]
region => “x”
index => "%{[tag]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
#index => "testing-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[type]}"
codec => "json"
}
}
if [type] == "ecstcp" {
amazon_es {
hosts => [“xx”]
region => “xx”
index => "%{[logstash_index]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
#index => "filetesting-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[type]}"
codec => "json"
}
}
}
```

Comment: I would first fix the wrong double quotes, i.e. use `"` instead of `“` (thank you MS Word)

Comment: Then I think you're going to have issues with your `[geoip][coordinates]` field